# Android app bundle not updating res value which we given inside application variant.all{}

Tags: android, gradle

When I generate apk from app bundle it always picking resValue which I have given inside defaultconfig.i am maintaining different resValue for different buildVariant inside application variant.all{}.
But it's not updating from application Variant.all{}.

Comment: i don't think Variant all is an option in built variant.

Comment: applicationVariants.all { variant -> }  this option is outside buildtype and productflavor block. I am updating resValue inside applicationVariant.all{}.but it's not updating. It's always picking from defaultConfig {} only

Comment: @santoshlokhande any solution for this ?

Comment: For now I updated this resValue inside variant.getPreBuildProvider().configure(){ it.doFirst { //Here I updated resValues }}